# Android Geofence Trigger w/No Network Connectivity

Tags: android, android-geofence

I added geofences to my Android app, and they work great when devices are connected to WiFi. Unfortunately some devices lose WiFi connectivity when the users exit their geofence, and thus are not connected to WiFi and do not have cellular network connectivity at the moment of 'exit'. The geofence triggers do not occur on these devices.

Is there anything to do as the developer / device user to make it so that the Geofence exit/enter events trigger even if there's no network connectivity (i.e. ideally by using the phone's GPS)

Answer (score 0):

Android Geofences depends mostly on location adapter being on or off.
Entry/dwell/exit triggers will come even if the wifi is on or off, in most cases.

Google Play services use wifi or device internet as an add-on to improve the accuracy, specifically for low radius zones.

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#Troubleshooting),
Starting from Android 4.3 (API level 18), **we added the capability of “Wi-Fi scan only mode”** which allows users to disable Wi-Fi but still get good network location. It’s good practice to prompt the user and provide a shortcut for the user to enable Wi-Fi or Wi-Fi scan only mode if both of them are disabled. Use **[SettingsClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient)** to ensure that the device's system settings are properly configured for optimal location detection.

Note: If your app targets Android 10 (API level 29) or higher, you cannot call WifiManager.setEnabled() directly unless your app is a system app or a device policy controller (DPC). Instead, use a settings panel.

Additionally, it's recommended to re- register your geofences in [these](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#re-register-geofences-only-when-required) cases.